# Procedimiento almacenado LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedure, aspx

estoy llamando a un procedimiento almacenado atraves de entityframework
pero me sale una excepción

Al momento de pasarle los parametros

```
exp="tblAdquiridosGe"

_cFiltros="'d.cNombre = ''DE'''"

 return contexto.uspBusquedaCliente(exp,_cFiltros)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando ejecuto la consulta directamente en SQLSERVER me arroja información
o simplemente si no encuentra nada, no devuelve nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Estoy pasandole los valores de manera correcta?

De antemano muchas gracias.

```
USE [GESTORIGECE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspBusquedaCliente]    Script Date: 22/08/2018 11:51:06 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspBusquedaCliente]
@Tablas VARCHAR(MAX),
@cFiltros VARCHAR(MAX)
AS

DECLARE @tblTablas TABLE
(
       cNombreTabla VARCHAR(200),
       bChecked BIT 
)


DECLARE @tblFiltros TABLE
(
       cFiltro VARCHAR(200),
       bChecked BIT 
)

INSERT INTO @tblTablas
SELECT Item, 0 FROM  [dbo].[udf_SplitString] (@Tablas, ',')

INSERT INTO @tblFiltros
SELECT Item, 0 FROM dbo.udf_SplitString (@cFiltros, '|')
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @cTabla VARCHAR(MAX), @Where VARCHAR(MAX) = ' 1 = 1', @cFiltro VARCHAR(200)

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @tblFiltros WHERE bChecked = 0)
BEGIN
       SELECT TOP 1 @cFiltro = cFiltro FROM @tblFiltros WHERE bChecked = 0

       SET @Where = @Where + ' AND ' + @cFiltro

       UPDATE @tblFiltros
       SET bChecked = 1
       WHERE cFiltro = @cFiltro

END

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @tblTablas WHERE bChecked = 0)
BEGIN
       SELECT TOP 1 @cTabla = cNombreTabla FROM @tblTablas WHERE bChecked = 0

       IF LEN(@SQL) > 0
       BEGIN
             SET @SQL = @SQL + '
                    UNION 
                    '
       END

       SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT m.cNombre as Municipio, l.cNombre as Localidad,d.cNombre as [Nombre del propietario],d.dSuperficie as Superficie,d.cRegion as Región,d.cManzana as Manzana,d.cSuperManzana as [Super Manzana], cLote,d.cClaveCatastral as [Clave Catastral],d.cEtiqueta as [Etiqueta del Expediente]
                           FROM tblDocumentos d
                           INNER JOIN ' + @cTabla + ' t1
                                 ON d.iIdDocumento = t1.iIdDocumento 
                           INNER JOIN tblCatLocalidades l
                                 ON d.iIdLocalidad = l.iIdLocalidad
                           INNER JOIN tblCatMunicipios m
                                 On l.iIdMunicipio = m.iIdMunicipio
                           WHERE ' + ISNULL(@Where, '')
       UPDATE @tblTablas
       SET bChecked = 1
       WHERE cNombreTabla = @cTabla

END

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL 



---

STORE

USE [GESTORIGECE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspBusquedaCliente]    Script Date: 22/08/2018 11:51:06 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspBusquedaCliente]
@Tablas VARCHAR(MAX),
@cFiltros VARCHAR(MAX)
AS

DECLARE @tblTablas TABLE
(
       cNombreTabla VARCHAR(200),
       bChecked BIT 
)


DECLARE @tblFiltros TABLE
(
       cFiltro VARCHAR(200),
       bChecked BIT 
)

INSERT INTO @tblTablas
SELECT Item, 0 FROM  [dbo].[udf_SplitString] (@Tablas, ',')

INSERT INTO @tblFiltros
SELECT Item, 0 FROM dbo.udf_SplitString (@cFiltros, '|')
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @cTabla VARCHAR(MAX), @Where VARCHAR(MAX) = ' 1 = 1', @cFiltro VARCHAR(200)

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @tblFiltros WHERE bChecked = 0)
BEGIN
       SELECT TOP 1 @cFiltro = cFiltro FROM @tblFiltros WHERE bChecked = 0

       SET @Where = @Where + ' AND ' + @cFiltro

       UPDATE @tblFiltros
       SET bChecked = 1
       WHERE cFiltro = @cFiltro

END

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @tblTablas WHERE bChecked = 0)
BEGIN
       SELECT TOP 1 @cTabla = cNombreTabla FROM @tblTablas WHERE bChecked = 0

       IF LEN(@SQL) > 0
       BEGIN
             SET @SQL = @SQL + '
                    UNION 
                    '
       END

       SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT m.cNombre as Municipio, l.cNombre as Localidad,d.cNombre as [Nombre del propietario],d.dSuperficie as Superficie,d.cRegion as Región,d.cManzana as Manzana,d.cSuperManzana as [Super Manzana], cLote,d.cClaveCatastral as [Clave Catastral],d.cEtiqueta as [Etiqueta del Expediente]
                           FROM tblDocumentos d
                           INNER JOIN ' + @cTabla + ' t1
                                 ON d.iIdDocumento = t1.iIdDocumento 
                           INNER JOIN tblCatLocalidades l
                                 ON d.iIdLocalidad = l.iIdLocalidad
                           INNER JOIN tblCatMunicipios m
                                 On l.iIdMunicipio = m.iIdMunicipio
                           WHERE ' + ISNULL(@Where, '')
       UPDATE @tblTablas
       SET bChecked = 1
       WHERE cNombreTabla = @cTabla

END

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido a [es.so]. Para que tu pregunta obtenga mayor atención deberás poner el código en texto, esto facilita a otros usuarios replicar tu escenario (en caso que eso sea posible). Respecto a tu problema, ¿puedes agregar el código del método `ExecuteFunction` para determinar lo qué pueda estar fallando.

Comment: ¿Podrias compartir el código donde llamas a tu SP? Ya que solo con la imagen es complicado poder asistirte.

Comment: El error podria estar en la creacion del objectparameter.
     new ObjectParameter("NOMBRE DEL CAMPO", VALOR);
     new ObjectParameter("NOMBRE DEL CAMPO", typeOf(string));

Comment: Ya puse el sp  c

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Pero si estas usando EntityFramework, haces CodeFirst? o DbFirst?. Podrias complementar los USP con DbFirst, y traerlos con entity al proyecto. Luego simplemente usarlos desde el contexto y listo. no tendrías que construir tantas cosas.

```
using (var context = new EF_DataBaseEntities())
            {
                var id = new ObjectParameter("id", typeof(long));
                context.USP_CUSTOMER_CREATE(data.Name, data.Address, data.BirthDate.ToDateTime(), data.DocumentId, data.DocumentType, data.CityId, id);
                context.SaveChanges();

                response.Code = StatusCode.Ok;
                response.Data = long.Parse(id.Value.ToString());
                response.Message = $"Usuario creado correctamente con ID {response.Data}";
            }
```